# Integrating CMS Ektron and MVC application

Tags: c#, content-management-system, ektron

I have two  separate applications, a c#  MVC app and a CMS (Ektron) app.  I want the user to be able to move between the two application seamlessly without having to log into each application separately. What it the best (easiest) way to achieve this? 
I sort of  have it working using web services but wonder if there is a better way.

TIA
Stuart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution sounds good.  Here is how I have done it in the past in case it helps you.  Use webservices so that one of your applications will be your login application.  Only one application will contain the webservice.  This application will use it's standard login, only logging the user into it.

On the other application, check to see it the user is logged in on every page load(preferably in a page baseclass).  If the user is not logged in, use the webservice that will log him into the login application.  If that returns successful, log the user into the this app programmatically.  This way you can use the builtin login functionality of each application without having to modify them.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to build and deploy the MVC app to a virtual directory within the Ektron web site. The mvc app uses the Ektron api t ocheck that the user is logged on and has the correct permissions, otherwise they are re-diected to the Ektron logon page.

The only actions that i needed to make in order for this to work were setting the mappings for the virtual directory to direct all requests to the aspnet_isapi.dll and then wrap the  section of the Ektron (root) web.config with

regards

Paul Durdin

Answer (score 0):

Ektron can run with MVC on the same box. My company has done it with 8.X.